# Get total number of words in a pdf

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to get total number of words in a pdf file. Is there any javascript library for this? React library would be wonderful as I am using react. Thanks.

Comment: "*Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow*". You can probably ask this on **https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com** but please read their [help pages](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [question quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336) before posting

Answer (score 2):

You can use npm package  [pdf-parse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-parse)

```
const fs = require('fs');
const pdf = require('pdf-parse');

let dataBuffer = fs.readFileSync('path to PDF file...');

function countWords(str) {
   str = str.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi,"");
   str = str.replace(/[ ]{2,}/gi," ");
   str = str.replace(/\n /,"\n");
   return str.split(' ').length;
   }

pdf(dataBuffer).then(function(data) {
   console.log(countWords(data.text));        
});
```